# Similar Title Suggestions in Review

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, review

I think it would be useful to have an interface like the "Questions with similar titles" in the review section. The actual implementation of such an interface is up for debate.

I realize that this won't help in *all* cases, but I feel like it could help in enough cases to be worthwhile.